# jasper report export to xls: extra margins

Tags: jasper-reports

I've set margins report -> page format -> margins,

[image]

it is ok for printing pdf

[image]

when exporting to xls I get extra space between page border and report contents

[image]

This breaks detail band pagination in more complex reports, I can't print such reports

here is report template, jasper version is 5.6

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1383480/work/Blank_A4_Landscape.jrxml

What's wrong with me :)? Where is origin of such extra margins?
Are there any workarounds?

Comment: i tried printing on physical printer: looks like excel only during print preview and printing sums these printer margins and layout margins, how this can be undone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Excel only during print preview and printing adds sepcific printer margins individual for each printer and this can't be undone